# Simplify meta-universally quantified assumptions with equality

Tags: isabelle

Sorry for not being able to come up with a shorter example.

I have a proof state of

```
 1. ⋀e1 T1 L e2 T2 G1.
       typing (G1 @ (x, U) # G2) e1 T1 ⟹
       typing (G1 @ G2) e1 T1 ⟹
       (⋀xa. xa |∉| L ⟹
              typing ((xa, T1) # G1 @ (x, U) # G2) (open e2 (exp_fvar xa))
               T2) ⟹
       (⋀xa G1a.
           xa |∉| L ⟹
           (xa, T1) # G1 = G1a ⟹
           x |∉| fv (open e2 (exp_fvar xa)) ⟹
           typing (G1a @ G2) (open e2 (exp_fvar xa)) T2) ⟹
       x |∉| fv e1 ⟹ x |∉| fv e2 ⟹ typing (G1 @ G2) (exp_let e1 e2) T2
```

Note the fourth premise (the large one): It universally meta-quantifies over `G1a`, but `G1a` is actually determined by the equation there. So it could just substitute this (and then simplify the conclusion of the premise) and `auto` would be able to solve the goal.

Can I make the simplifier solve this?

I guess a small example is

```
lemma foo:
  "(⋀ G.  x#xs = G ⟹ P x ⟹ f G) ⟹ f (x#xs)"
apply simp
```

There is a somewhat related question about [equalities under existentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33147980/946226).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can only be solved reliably using a simproc. The `induct` proof method in `~~/src/Tools/induct.ML` already has an implementation for this, so you might be able to adapt the code. The idea is that you move the equations to the front using `Induct.rearrange_eqs_simproc` and then use appropriate one point rules to eliminate the equality.